# Install of NodeJs failed without an explanation. Here's the log

Tags: node.js, windows-7

I executed MSIExec.exe on my Windows 7 64-bit machine with an option to log to a file:

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-installer-

executable_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_a7a77a3b9cb96ce6\msiexec.exe /log 

installer.log /i "D:\Users\Chad\Downloads\node-v0.12.2-x64.msi"
```

And got a message that the install failed and was rolled back.

The log was too long to include in the message, so I posted it [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=ABE50FEC08EAAFF0&id=abe50fec08eaaff0%215610) on One Drive.

Here's the truncated log, reduced in size for posting. Hopefully I didn't remove anything that might reveal the issue.

```
=== Logging started: 4/22/2015  20:54:54 ===
Action 20:54:54: INSTALL. 
Action start 20:54:54: INSTALL.
Action 20:54:54: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 20:54:54: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 20:54:54: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: PrepareDlg. 
Action start 20:54:54: PrepareDlg.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Normal textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Bigger textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 19 pixels height.
Action 20:54:54: PrepareDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 20:54:54: PrepareDlg. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 20:54:54: AppSearch.
AppSearch: Property: INSTALLDIR, Signature: InstallPathRegistry
Action ended 20:54:54: AppSearch. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 20:54:54: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 20:54:54: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 20:54:54: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 20:54:54: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:54:54: CostInitialize.
Action ended 20:54:54: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:54:54: FileCost.
Action ended 20:54:54: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 20:54:54: CostFinalize.
Action ended 20:54:54: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 20:54:54: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 20:54:54: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 20:54:54: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action 20:54:54: WelcomeDlg. 
Action start 20:54:54: WelcomeDlg.
Action 20:54:54: WelcomeDlg. Dialog created
Info 2898.For WixUI_Font_Title textstyle, the system created a 'Tahoma' font, in 0 character set, of 14 pixels height.
Action 20:54:56: LicenseAgreementDlg. Dialog created
Action 20:54:58: InstallDirDlg. Dialog created
Action 20:55:02: CustomizeDlg. Dialog created
Action 20:55:04: VerifyReadyDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 20:55:05: WelcomeDlg. Return value 1.
Action 20:55:05: ProgressDlg. 
Action start 20:55:05: ProgressDlg.
Action 20:55:05: ProgressDlg. Dialog created
Action ended 20:55:05: ProgressDlg. Return value 1.
Action 20:55:05: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 20:55:05: ExecuteAction.
Action ended 20:55:05: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
Action 20:55:05: FatalError. 
Action start 20:55:05: FatalError.
Action 20:55:05: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 20:55:06: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 20:55:06: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {1D60944C-B9CE-4A71-A7C0-0384EB884BAA}
Property(C): INSTALLDIR = D:\Program Files\nodejs\
Property(C): LicenseAccepted = 1
Property(C): ApplicationProgramsFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js\
Property(C): NpmFolder = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
Property(C): dir2DBC1DAB11A12FCAC6C332391DF3E58F = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
Property(C): dir177C36B8D0E9124560703C42786625CB = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\
Property(C): dir2E059758C63799830EDBCC99AF4F29F0 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\
Property(C): dir730550B8529EC5D41FD713FDC1AEA10E = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\doc\api\
Property(C): dir487D0A02FE1E5CDCED4851E7EB08F6F3 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\doc\cli\
Property(C): dirDEAB04BA48166540AA6DCE45076E789B = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\doc\files\
Property(C): dir4CD974A3DF15686C9ADB4AA7BABDB787 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\doc\misc\
Property(C): dir4C6B531DFFA66BFAAD7215C318202B2E = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\html\

{A bunch of similar messages deleted to reduce post size}


Property(C): dir5175A9E22BE8EA63836C6D60FE197FC6 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\shrinkwrap-empty-deps\
Property(C): dir85DCAD94C73E28E566F52354ACF79510 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\shrinkwrap-shared-dev-dependency\
Property(C): dir5FBF5A041EF168AA0831872588156E2F = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\startstop\
Property(C): dirA4AE3554AF7589CAB66352D60CF30C06 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\uninstall-package\
Property(C): dir2C8B1A1F06F6B24013B3F6C5EA2805DE = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\unpack-foreign-tarball\
Property(C): dirBEF3EE48F700A2FABC4780F679622D05 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\update-save\
Property(C): dir8D662D11942BBF070DB6096A9E69150C = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\url-dependencies\
Property(C): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(C): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIR
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(C): TARGETDIR = D:\
Property(C): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(C): SourceDir = D:\Users\Chad\Downloads\
Property(C): NodeModulesFolder = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
Property(C): dir27FF552EDD00ADAFA62117E9689DD44C = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\doc\
Property(C): dirFDA38908CF5DD1F5C2AA218214F828F7 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\html\partial\
Property(C): dir36DCD06BBFB6527C1F682CED69041F19 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\man\
Property(C): dirC2B43B080829B409A932A431DBCB088E = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
Property(C): dirF214B9DC5C52FC5823E5237136B9BC72 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\columnify\node_modules\
Property(C): dir3152D62629128300C981B7C3C12A49D0 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\columnify\node_modules\strip-ansi\node_modules\
Property(C): dirF90EDE2519A1C09DE05720D0E1AAF35F = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\columnify\node_modules\wcwidth\node_modules\
Property(C): dirD8B3DBBCD28BCC5A4A45B0C1741A2A57 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\columnify\node_modules\wcwidth\node_modules\defaults\node_modules\
Property(C): dirAECD6441E1439E1C1154C19B5BCF67F5 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\node_modules\
Property(C): dir0DC19119A145B1A202A289C5810132DB = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\dezalgo\node_modules\
Property(C): dir31DBC0FC4224C2BB0CD7703096D9E014 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream-npm\node_modules\
Property(C): dirB459E5B3BDE9C2ADE63BADDBA18EE8E5 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\init-package-json\node_modules\
Property(C): dir21427A9DAAB14439CA79B24614485361 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\
Property(C): dir5C692A00A15A045894C7F9ED060B3291 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\brace-expansion\node_modules\
Property(C): dir3B82412B84C4272A732FF8E05E229C15 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\node_modules\
Property(C): dir0A40A58DE625D74A4EC122F8D27DC1E8 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\data\
Property(C): dir175497BAC1EB93A05940EDF8F4FAA437 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\
Property(C): dir611B36408EC82729C6CA5840AC1456D1 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\
Property(C): dir94B9D7EEE413B5FBEAE8D6C7D4F77D6B = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\glob\node_modules\
Property(C): dir94B4D67EC04F3A4B23989730B7F05245 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\
Property(C): dir9667932BE641E83D0D49D9C387064B1E = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\brace-expansion\node_modules\
Property(C): dirECB730AE7C7B11210B23763DF4D5FD8A = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\
Property(C): dir07B8BFC118C1177ED268677A581BC97E = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\
Property(C): dir6253E6FE86FF6447CA2B9E02EAD737BE = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\
Property(C): dirD792C030B38819930E0338861F158553 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\
Property(C): dirBD6CD5296CD68909AC137C645DD334D5 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\test\fixtures\@npm\
Property(C): dirCD6BDEDD1FB89402186919FF4A0CC1CD = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\test\fixtures\
Property(C): dir0C5167A73F9E3894B68A178503F84E87 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\
Property(C): dir6FC330CA496477960F4C1EBB7322785A = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\are-we-there-yet\node_modules\
Property(C): dirD416CF4172AA77DC03BE5BC63625FA33 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\
Property(C): dirE51F9ADCC0ADB6132D0823A5F86CDD11 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npmlog\node_modules\gauge\node_modules\lodash._createpad\node_modules\
Property(C): dir4C21815F475A59AFCE62589C9CF33FEF = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read\node_modules\
Property(C): dirB0A5AF4D11700791C542B220ACDE8661 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\node_modules\
Property(C): dirB9C9F898FBB7D4A32F4D6B160ED47369 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules\test\fixtures\@org\
Property(C): dirE410333B3E321B59DE5A03FF3A686F60 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules\test\fixtures\
Property(C): dir8D76A9AA5AB2208AE3BEFE31A54BB7A0 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules\test\fixtures\@scope\
Property(C): dirED2482DFD30E70F187A8FB47983F94B3 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules\test\fixtures\a\
Property(C): dirE6083DBC42DEC79C958E8A0184E6C7B4 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules\test\fixtures\b\
Property(C): dirC5D9479C6FB2EE3884A297EC499C32D9 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\
Property(C): dirD5EACD0575FCB8B99D34AD39C0E486DF = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\json-parse-helpfulerror\node_modules\
Property(C): dir03DF7F765B6AF4D0361BCA0F3D04BA24 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\
Property(C): dir22D756E654310E33C222F5C1F86F096A = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\
Property(C): dir88EE5F210052B6618E19712A284CEF3B = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\
Property(C): dirEE9C523F4092E1B2E1DF817345A9C771 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\
Property(C): dir52BA202DDE1005CD0D327A80B4729EB2 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\node_modules\is-my-json-valid\node_modules\
Property(C): dir55F6EA180EA31885B57EC99462B0C40B = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\node_modules\is-my-json-valid\
Property(C): dir1850DE9147531DC1E23CB901CA5F4B7F = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\node_modules\
Property(C): dirF17180A80373ED8B9EA8A72B5B47E9EC = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-validator\
Property(C): dir6F2DA96C0CC4CC569DC10C7D71B33F7F = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\hawk\node_modules\
Property(C): dir86C48A670BCA37542794E40A947DEAF3 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\node_modules\
Property(C): dir80DA0FAE4F4D944C4BAE0DED77F5B6BE = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\node_modules\asn1\tst\
Property(C): dir79A91675728C58981A8C42000FC82980 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\node_modules\ctype\man\
Property(C): dir36CEDA85D8E87FBD4D0815F90FBA96E0 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\mime-types\node_modules\
Property(C): dir96861D4231F9B406DFD16E9D9DB04C78 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\node_modules\
Property(C): dir555C3D7C05EE2A2CBA0F3FB1FC2733A8 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\rimraf\node_modules\
Property(C): dir244C51B835D14053E04C05C65DCBAFC1 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\node_modules\
Property(C): dir6AB4E3725ACF493E08C499779CE34960 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\
Property(C): dirF758897189FA2C6D9A49B13625745BDD = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\disabled\
Property(C): dir32440D5F5C4665CC655029F727190409 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\
Property(C): dir57ABA764871C14C5A984E1B8FBE20293 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\packages\npm-test-ignore-nested-nm\lib\
Property(C): dir14EDF0EB6690514844B14B4707B0F71D = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\circular-dep\
Property(C): dir81E716DA9FB93DE53D89845543809817 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\install-at-locally\
Property(C): dir5CB635413E9FB3230CA851D311809982 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\install-from-local\
Property(C): dirB07B3BDD3581C7B1690510AAB4DC0F03 = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\install-save-local\
Property(C): dirE582153DA993B7F47885AA5132D6CFAD = D:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\test\tap\optional-metadep-rollback-collision\deps\
Property(C): ARPPRODUCTICON = NodeIcon
Property(C): ApplicationFolderName = nodejs
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = WixUI_Font_Normal
Property(C): WixUI_Mode = FeatureTree
Property(C): WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT = Node.js has been successfully installed.
Property(C): Manufacturer = Joyent, Inc. and other Node contributors
Property(C): ProductCode = {40435563-20B0-4DA3-8E52-E5BF28ABE5C3}
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(C): ProductName = Node.js
Property(C): ProductVersion = 0.12.2
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDlg
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = C:\Users\Chad\installer.log
Property(C): PackageCode = {7AF18F48-7F4A-4FB4-98A6-3E711FD98583}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Users\Chad
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 9476
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(C): VersionNT = 601
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 601
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 7601
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 1
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = D:\Windows\Temp\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(C): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = D:\Users\Tess\Documents\Cucusoft Backup\Favorites\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = D:\Users\Chad\Documents\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = d:\Users\Chad\AppData\Local\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = D:\Users\Chad\Pictures\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = D:\Users\Chad\Desktop\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(C): Msix64 = 6
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 6135
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 6620
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): MsiTrueAdminUser = 1
Property(C): LogonUser = Chad
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-2504967445-3377560918-3782464836-1000
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(C): ComputerName = BESI-CHAD
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(C): ScreenX = 1920
Property(C): ScreenY = 1080
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 22
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 20:55:06
Property(C): Date = 4/22/2015
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.34209
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.1.7601.17514
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = Chad
Property(C): DATABASE = D:\Users\Chad\Downloads\node-v0.12.2-x64.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase = D:\Users\Chad\Downloads\node-v0.12.2-x64.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = D:\Users\Chad\Downloads\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): ROOTDRIVE = D:\
Property(C): CostingComplete = 1
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
=== Logging stopped: 4/22/2015  20:55:06 ===
MSI (c) (04:9C) [20:55:06:968]: Product: Node.js -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (04:9C) [20:55:06:969]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Node.js. Product Version: 0.12.2. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Joyent, Inc. and other Node contributors. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

**Do you have any idea what exactly failed and how to resolve?**

Thanks

A recent install of msysgit (Git-1.9.5-preview20150319.exe) from https://msysgit.github.io/, I believe, corrupted my PATH variable. When I restored it, NODEJS installed successfully.

**Update**

Bower "installed without error" but my PATH variable was set to

C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Roaming\npm

and everything else is trashed.

**Update 2**

I noticed that all of my Control Panel links didn't work after installing Bower because the systen variable %winDir% was no longer set. Since the list to the Advanced Properties editor that was used to manage the System Variables no longer worked due to the WinDir variable no longer being set (%winDir%\system32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe) I instead ran c:\Windows\system32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe) and it came up. Everything looked as it should, including seeing the WinDir System variable set, but still when I ran ECHO %windir% from the CLI, it showed that it was not set.

I don't get what the BOWER Install is doing to my PC, but I don't like it. To recover my ENV variables back, I use System Restore to get my PC working as it was prior to the Bower install, but with Bower not working.

Curious. I still have some Bower files on my PC. If I type in NPM from the command line, what should that execute? I don't recall seeing an npm.exe or npm.bat file anywhere on my PC when I tried a npm bower install -g. The npm command was previously recognized but the install failed.

I'm not sure how bower works. I was just wanting to try it out and I can't even install the bugger without trashing other aspects of my PC.

**Update 3**

After several attempts, I decided to clean up my SYSTEM PATH  variable and remove obsolete items. In doing so, I noticed a couple of duplicates, which I removed. When I re-installed after, I had no issue. Unless there is something else going on here, I assume that duplicates perhaps confused the logic that was supposed to update the PATH variable and a bad update was made. I'm not sure, I'm just relaying the outcome in case it helps the next person...

Comment: fyi,  unchecking creating online documentation did not work. Also, I am the Admin.

Comment: Did you try the steps listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834484)?  I just searched for that error code.

Comment: @  Aaron Dufour: yes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem installing on Windows 7, using all the defaults. So I restored Windows, like you did, and rebuilt my icon db. Then I tried again, without creating documentation shortcuts. I had the same problem again, then found your question. So I removed some path duplicates, like you described in your update 3, and everything worked. (I would've just left a comment under your question, but I don't have enough points to do that yet)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wasn't sure that removing the duplicates was the actual resolution or if it was just a coincidence but your similar experience seems to indicate that it probably was the issue. I'm glad that I took the time to document the apparent solution so that you were able to benefit. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Having the same errors installing Node 6.5.0 on Win7x64.  Verified every directory in both my machine and my profile paths, removed duplicates.  Still no dice.  Good thought!  But you might be right about it being coincidental.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem, I have resolved my issue. I just mark `performance counter` to Install when required during **installation** of node.js.[image]